# What cleaup function can be applied to this useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, entity-framework, react-hooks

I can't figure out what cleanup function can I apply in this useEffect hook.It is working fine without a cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
            const fetchProfileUser = async () => {
                if (profileUserId === existingUser._id) {
                    setprofileUser(existingUser);
                } else {
                    const profileUser = await UserApi.getUser(profileUserId);
                    setprofileUser(profileUser);
                }
            };
            fetchProfileUser();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't always need a cleanup function. But most of the time you need dependency array in `useEffect`, even it is empty. If you are doing requests, you definitely need an dependency array.

If you are doing request, you can use AbortController to cancel the request using cleanup function, if that component gets unmounted.